# Problemas al unir dos tablas sql y comparar si existe

Tags: sql-server, sql

Quiero obtener una consulta donde regrese la Cve, Nombre y Existe,
en una tabla tengo  el catalago y en otra tengo las que existe, por lo tanto quiero obtener todo el catalago pero con un campo extra que este en 1 las que existan y en 0 las que estén

```js
**tabla catalago:**CAMPOS
cve_ventana|nombre

**tabla roles** CAMPOS
fk_cve_Ventana

**NECESITO GENERAR ESTO:**

Cve_Ventana | Nombre | Existe
1           |carro   |1      | <- que si existe en la tabla roles 
2           |llantas |0      |<- no esta en la tabla roles

Quiero obtener todos los registro de la tabla T_Ventanas y los registros que no estén en T_Roles me los marque como "0" en Existe
```

Comment: Y cuál es la pregunta? Qué pasa cuando usas esa consulta que tienes en tu pregunta?

Comment: y si pruebas generando una subconsulta así  SELECT * FROM
    (
       Cve_Ventana,Nombre,'0' as Existe FROM T_Ventanas 
          UNION
       SELECT FK_Cve_Ventana,null,'1' FROM t_roles
    ) AS U
    WHERE FK_Cve_TipoUsuario=2;

Comment: cuando hago la consulta obtengo lo siguiente:http://prntscr.com/jyi2yp  en ves de agruparlos, me aparecen abajo pero en null y con el valor de 1 y lo que necesito es imprimir solo 1, ya sea 1 o 0  imagen:http://prntscr.com/jyi35q,

Answer (score 2):

Creo que el tipo de unión que necesitas aquí es un `LEFT JOIN`, el cual te dará `NULL` en los no coincidentes. Basándote en ese mismo valor, puedes usar un `CASE WHEN` para mostrar `1` ó `0` evaluando alguna columna de la tabla que unirás con el `LEFT JOIN`.

Lo de agrupar o no lo dejo a tu criterio, y sería necesario solamente en el caso de que haya varias filas con el mismo id en la tabla foránea.

La consulta sería así:

### `a`. Con SQL Server

Puedes ver una **<kbd>[DEMO COMPLETA EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/DKKVY58888)</kbd>**, operando sobre datos reales.

```
SELECT 
    c.cve_ventana, 
    c.nombre, 
    CASE WHEN r.fk_cve_Ventana IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 'Existe' 
FROM catalogo c 
LEFT JOIN roles r
ON c.cve_ventana = r.fk_cve_Ventana;
```

### `b.` Con MySQL

Puedes ver una **<kbd>[DEMO COMPLETA EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/KQZP42623)</kbd>**, operando sobre datos reales.

En MySQL se puede usar un `IF`, del siguiente modo:

```
SELECT 
    c.cve_ventana, 
    c.nombre, 
    IF(r.fk_cve_Ventana,'1','0') Existe 
FROM catalogo c 
LEFT JOIN roles r
ON c.cve_ventana = r.fk_cve_Ventana;
```

---

Tanto en **`a.`** como en  **`b.`** el resultado sería:

```
Cve_Ventana | Nombre | Existe|
1           |carro   |1      | 
2           |llantas |0      |
```

Comment: Intenté implementarlo en sql server y me marca error:  SELECT c.Cve_Ventana,c.NombreOpcion,IF(r.FK_Cve_Ventana,'1','0')as existe
FROM T_Ventanas c 
JOIN T_Roles r ON r.FK_Cve_Ventana=c.Cve_Ventana
GROUP BY c.Cve_Ventana                                                                                                                Error:Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.

Comment: @ffff, esta es la respuesta indicada, pero para sql-server, modificando `IF(r.fk_cve_Ventana,'1','0') Existe` por `CASE WHEN r.fk_cve_Ventana IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 'Existe'`, debiera funcionar. Para la próxima recuerda usar una sola etiqueta para el motor de base de datos. Saludos

Comment: Solo me aparecen las que existen en la tabla T_Roles y me aparecen en "1", pero las que no existen en la tabla T_Roles  no me las enlistan con el '0'

Comment: @ffff, si estás usando el `LEFT JOIN` tal como te ha respondido A.Cedano, no veo que pueda suceder lo que estás diciendo, me suena más a que estás usando el `JOIN` simple.

Comment: ¿Respondí basándome en MySQL por error? Parece que no me fijé en la etiqueta SQL Server. Cómo ha dicho @PatricioMoracho debería funcionar con `CASE ... WHEN` en cuanto pueda actualizo la respuesta y la demo.

Comment: @A.Cedano, originalmente tenía la de `mysql` también. Saludos.

Comment: @ffff he actualizado la respuesta, indicando cómo sería en SQL Server. Lo puedes probar también en la demo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo en MySQL con una condición, si existe es 1 y si no 0.

```
SELECT c.* ,
IF (fk_cve_ventana = cve_ventana,1,0) AS existe
FROM catalogo c 
JOIN roles r ON r.fk_cve_ventana=c.cve_ventana
GROUP BY c.cve_ventana
```

Comment: no me funcionó :( me marca error con una ,

Comment: la necesito en sql server y al parecer no funciona así

Comment: Entonces debes hacerlo con CASE... WHEN. Veo que ya has corregido la etiqueta de MySQL.